# Cookie not available across sub-domains in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, subdomain

On sub-domain sub1.mysite.com, my javascript sets a cookie as such:

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=acookievalue;expires=;path=/;domain=.mysite.com;";
```

In Chrome/Firefox, I am able to read the cookie value with no problem from another sub-domain, say sub2.mysite.com.

However, on IE, this cookie does not seem to be available. I have looked online and have seen that IE has some kinks, but I am not sure if a workaround exists. Initially, I discovered having expires with no date did not set the cookie on IE. I then removed the property entirely. I also discovered that IE would not set a cookie when I included the path property. So the only working cookie I've been able to set in IE is as such:

```
"myCookie=acookievalue;domain=mysite.com"
```

Still, when the sub-domain opens, it cannot read this cookie.

The purpose of setting this cookie is to display a message (the value of the cookie) on the other sub-domain when it opens in a separate window (`window.open("sub2.mysite.com")`). `postMessage` won't work for me because I need **IE8-9** support, which only works for frames.

Appreciate any help or other possible solutions.

Comment: Do your subdomains start with a number or contain an underscore?  The cookies should work across all subdomains...

Comment: They do not. I did see some articles mentioning invalid subdomain causing the issues, but this is not the case.